# Computing the closed subschemes of the projective line over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

(Specifically, this is III-15 in E&H, but I feel like I've hit a brick wall in actually applying the definitions they've given to this example.)

In Chapter I of *The Geometry of Schemes,* E&H define the closed subscheme $Y \subseteq X$ associated to an ideal $I \subseteq R$ by quotienting $\mathscr{O}_X$ by the sheaf of ideals $\mathscr{J}$ induced by sending basic open sets $X_f \mapsto I \cdot R_f$, so that (denoting by $j$ the inclusion $|Y| \hookrightarrow |X|$) we have $j_*(\mathscr{O}_Y) = \mathscr{O}_X / \mathscr{J}.$

How do I show, using this definition, that the closed subschemes defined by the ideals $(x_0)$ and $(x_0^2,x_0x_1)$ consist of one point and are identical? (In particular, how can I figure out what $\mathscr{J}$ looks like by computing what the ideals look like under localization for each basic open set?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associated ideal sheaf you you define makes sense only for affine schemes. For a projective scheme $X$ with projective coordinate ring $S$, given a homogeneous element $f \in S_+$ the basic open set it defines is $D_+(f)=Spec{ S_{(f)}}$.
So the corresponding ideal should be the zero grading of the ideal $I \cdot S_f$.
Globally you just need to take the homogeneous ideal $I=(f)$.
In your case these are the ideals $I=(x_0)$ and $I=(x_0^2,x_0x_1)$.

---

The projective line $\mathbb{P}^1_A = Proj {A[x_0,x_1]}$ over a ring $A$ is covered by the open sets $U_i= \{x_i \neq 0 \}$, $i=0,1$.
These sets are affine $U_i = Spec{A[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\frac{x_1}{x_i}]}=\mathbb{A}^1_A$. Also $A[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\frac{x_1}{x_i}]$ is the zero grading of the localization $A[x_0,x_1]_{x_i}$.
The ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ corresponding to a closed subscheme defines ideals $\mathcal{I}(U_i) \subset A[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\frac{x_1}{x_i}]$. Now you can apply everything you know about affine schemes to the $U_i$'s.

Comment: Does this help or to add more details?

Comment: I'm processing; this does help, thank you :); if possible, could elaborate on how this follows from the general definition of a closed subscheme of an arbitrary scheme defined by an ideal?